# Does Power BI support Incremental refresh for expanded table?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have made table as follows (https://apexinsights.net/blog/convert-date-range-to-list):

In this scenario suppose I configure Incremental refresh on the Start Date column, then will Power BI support this correctly. I am asking because - say the refresh is for last 2 days or last 2 months, then it will fetch the source rows, and apply the transform to the partition. But my concern is that I will have to put the date param filter on Start date prior to non folding steps so that the query folds (alternatively power query will auto apply date filter so that query can fold).

So when it pulls the data based on start date and apply the transforms then I'm not able to think clearly about what kind of partitions it will create. Whether it is for Start date or for expabded date. Is query folding supported in this scenario?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have 4 or 5 open questions all around the same topics. Do you still need answers to all of them?

Comment: Ofcourse this aspect of incremental refresh isn't discussed in any documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite complicated scenario, where I would probably just avoid adding incremental refresh.

You would have to use the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters twice in this query.  Once that gets folded to the data source to retrieve ranges that overlap with the [RangeStart,RangeEnd) interval and a second time after expanding the ranges to filter out individual rows that fall outside [RangeStart,RangeEnd).